# Why setting the key constraints on column removes "NOT NULL" from it (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql

I have the code to create a table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `database`.`creatures_kinds` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `database`.`creatures_kinds` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `name_en` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `parent_id`),
  INDEX `parent_id` (`parent_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `parent`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`)
    REFERENCES `database`.`creatures_kinds` (`id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

What surprise me is that the newly created table looks like this:
[image]

Why the `parent_id` is set to `NOT NULL` when I wrote `NULL` in the `CREATE TABLE`?

Does it has something to do with the `PRIMARY KEY` or `FOREIGN KEY`?

I guess that `parent_id` is an identifiable relation (it points to more general creature kind, e.g. from `pigeon` to `bird`, and it's `NULL` for top-level creature kinds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A `PRIMARY KEY` is a unique index where all key columns must be defined as `NOT NULL`. If they are not explicitly declared as `NOT NULL`, MySQL declares them so implicitly (and silently). [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html)